# where can i find pyqt examples folder in Mac Os x?

Tags: pyqt4

I've installed pyqt on mac os x and it's up and running well. But i can't find the pyqt examples folder? May i know where this is located by default..

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access them fast is via a github mirror:

**PyQt5**

https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/

**PyQt4**

https://github.com/ipatrol/pyqt4/tree/devel/PyQt-win-gpl-snapshot-4.8.4-69c456457274/examples

Comment: How does one use these?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius simply download to your machine, cd into the `examples/`directory and run it using `python <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tell us how did you actually install PyQt.  If you do it via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/), which I recommend, your port name is `qt4-mac`.  (You can check it via `port list installed` command.)

By default the installation doesn't include demos or examples.  You can include both with:

```
sudo port install qt4-mac +demos +examples
```

This procedure is quite slow, up to several hours.

In `/opt/local/share/qt4/` folder you'll find `demos` and `examples`, and in `Applications/MacPorts/Qt4` will be `qtdemo`.